# Can we use ion thrusters in space to relieve tension on a space elevator cable?

Tags: civil-engineering, aerospace-engineering

I suspect/hope I'm not kidding myself too much with the physics of this; it seems to stack up in my mind; but can we not relieve tension on, say, a steel cable running from a space station in orbit around the Earth by propelling the station towards the Earth using ion thrusters, thereby relieving tension? Bear in mind that this idea came about after I began working on a design for a new space elevator consisting of about 100 stages of about 1km each stretching to the Karman line; I was planning on using turbofan jet engines and dirigibles up to the end of the stratosphere, and then rings of rocket engines after that to stabilise the whole thing and relieve tension; now I'm thinking it might just be good enough to simply use ion thrusters in space to counteract the tension on the cable. Is there any reason why that wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tension on the cable is due to centrifugal<sup>1</sup> force.

So, to help (at all) you need something that produces more thrust downward than its mass will produce in centrifugal force upward.

I'm pretty sure no current ion thruster even comes close to that. For example, NASA's X3 ion thruster weighs about 500 pounds, and produces about 1.2 pounds of thrust.

You'd also pretty much need to deliver power through the cable as well, which makes the problem even more difficult. The X3 thruster needs 250 amps of electricity to deliver its 1.2 pounds of thrust. In normal situations, to carry 250 amps, you'd use a wire around 00 to 0000 AWG (depending on distance). The distance you're dealing with is *much* greater than either of those is designed for though. To keep cabling halfway reasonable, you'd almost certainly want to run (much) higher voltage over the cable and step it down at the thruster to get the necessary current. Oh, but that (you can probably guess it) is going to add its own weight/mass, leading to more centrifugal force to overcome.

Until or unless ion thrusters have *drastically* higher thrust/mass ratio, this seems like a losing proposition. Even with drastically improved thrust/mass ratio, power delivery is likely to remain problematic as well.

**Reference**

https://newatlas.com/x3-hall-thruster-test-record-nasa/51869/

---

<sup>1. For the moment, ignoring phrasing details about centrifugal vs. centripetal force.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's incredibly useful to know. The only other option that seems like it'd plausibly work is rocket engines. It'd need rocket engines therefore I guess from the end of the stratosphere to this end station at the Karman line. I guess it's really another topic in its own right, but I was planning on preburning oxidiser and propellant on the ground and then (somehow) piping it up to where it's needed, to minimise things that could go wrong at high altitude, and to save weight. Thanks again, that was very helpful.

Comment: @SamCottle: The problem with rocket engines would be delivering fuel. For example, stage 1 of a Saturn V used about 20 tons of fuel per *second*.

Comment: Yeah, was hoping to use the vacuum at the top to exploit the Venturi effect. a

Answer (score 0):

Ion thrusters generate extremely low thrusts generally below one newton. I highly doubt they would be applicable as you intend. Even with very low thrust levels, ion thrusters are extremely efficient which is why they are used where they can be.